# Mysql Query to get the following result

Tags: mysql

Following table represents the subjects that have been chosen by students.

TABLE : 
**CourseMap**

[image]

I want to display result as follow, where subject chosen by each stud_id are displayed as columns:

[image]

Comment: you can do it with query or by creating a view

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be

```
select stud_id, 
       group_concat(sub_id order by sub_id) as subs
from your_table
group by stud_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use pivoting logic here:

```
SELECT
    stud_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN sub_id REGEXP '[0-9]$'  THEN sub_id END) AS sub_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN sub_id REGEXP '[0-9]P$' THEN sub_id END) AS sub_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN sub_id REGEXP 'A$'      THEN sub_id END) AS sub_3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN sub_id REGEXP 'AP$'     THEN sub_id END) AS sub_4
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    stud_id
ORDER BY
    stud_id;
```

The above query works, taking the first `CASE` expression as an example, by taking the maximum value of `sub_id` for each `stud_id` group, when that `sub_id` value ends in a digit.  This only happens for one of the four values, and in that case the `CASE` expression just returns that value.  Otherwise, it would return `NULL`, which would then be ignored.  Similar logic applies for the other `CASE` expressions.

Comment: @Phenom This is just a standard pivot query.  I will explain how one of the `CASE` expressions is working.

Comment: I'm seeing regular expressions in Mysql first time.